# Is there a C++ way to invoke linux shell commands?

Tags: c++, linux, shell

In C there is popen() and system() to invoke external commands. Is there a more standardized way in C++ to do this using for instance STL and 'std::'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Comment: No. BTW C++ was always designed with backward C compatibility in mind

Comment: Wow not to be snarky but you could have typed your question into Google or Bing or whatever instead of the new question page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. it's the same as the C one.

`#include <cstdlib>` and then use `std::system("whatever your command is")`.